# Verifying the existence of a number in a Play Scala form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3

I have a form where there is a number expected... I'm having a hard time verifying whether it has been submitted or not to return a message saying that it's required, I tried the following cases but none worked:

```
"orderBy" -> number.verifying("The order is required",_.isInstanceOf[Int])

"orderBy" -> number.verifying("The order is required",_>0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `orderBy` isn't submitted with the `Form` at all, then it will return a `FormError` with the key `error.required`.

I assume you mean the case when an empty `String` is submitted instead of number. The problem with your attempts is that the `verifying` functions are never reached, because the empty `String` doesn't make it past the `number` validator.

The only thing I can think of is making a custom `Mapping[Int]` that first checks to see if the field is empty, then checks to see if it's a valid `Int`.

```
val requiredNumber: Mapping[Int] = Forms.nonEmptyText
    .verifying("Must be numeric", i => Try(i.toInt).isSuccess || i.isEmpty)
    .transform[Int](_.toInt, _.toString)
```

And testing:

```
scala> val form = Form(mapping("orderBy" -> requiredNumber)(identity)(Some(_)))

scala> form.bind(Map("orderBy" -> "1")).value
res24: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> form.bind(Map("orderBy" -> "")).errors
res26: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List(FormError(orderBy,List(error.required),WrappedArray()))

scala> form.bind(Map("orderBy" -> "aa")).errors
res27: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List(FormError(orderBy,List(Must be numeric),WrappedArray()))

scala> form.bind(Map("orderByzzz" -> "2")).errors
res28: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List(FormError(orderBy,List(error.required),List()))
```